# Shell script that inserts text to last line of a file based on user input

Tags: linux, shell, variables, echo, user-input

```
#!/bin/sh
...
read var
#user enters: it doesn't work
...
echo 'Some text and $var' > myfile.txt
```

Expected output:

```
cat myfile.txt
#Some text and it doesn't work
```

Actual output:

```
cat myfile.txt
#Some text and $var
```

So how to echo the content into the file with the value of the `$var` variable?

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single one. echo " "

Comment: Worked! Thank you @Rakesh.N!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use double quote instead of simple quote to make variable remplacement available

you can also remove your quotes to make it work but it's not recommanded

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert $var to last line(=append the content $var to file), please use >>

should be:

```
echo "Some text and $var" >> myfile.txt
```

the > is to override the content, whereas >> is to append the content to a file